# Interlace PDF documents, replacing existing matching pages?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have two PDF documents.  One with a bunch of pages, and a second with fewer pages which supersede the the same named pages in the first PDF document.

For instance, document1 has:

- M1.01
- M1.02
- M1.03
- M1.04
- M1.05

and document2 has:

- M1.02
- M1.04
- M1.06

I wish to create a new document which includes the following

- M1.01 (from document1)
- M1.02 (from document2)
- M1.03 (from document1)
- M1.04 (from document2)
- M1.05 (from document1)
- M1.06 (from document2)

I actually have much more pages in each (around 300 in document1 and 50 in document2).

Is it possible to do so without manually cutting and pasting pages from one document to the other?

EDIT Each page in the document has a page number in the exact same place in the bottom right corner which might be able to match up the individual pages in both documents (see below).  Another possibility is if PDF documents assign a unique name to each page in a document (I don't know whether this is the case).

[image]

Comment: How would a program be able to tell that page 1 in document 2 is to replace page 2 in document 1?
Or are they "zipped": pick one from document 1, pick one from document 2, discard one from document 1, repeat.

Comment: @Edi.  Each page is in one single document.  See my edited original post where I describe page numbers for each page.

Comment: @user1032531: I assume you created the [bluebeam] tag since this was the only question with it.  In general, manufacturer meta tags are something we're trying to get rid of (see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again).  But a dedicated tag for little-known software can hurt rather than help.  Lots of people follow general pdf-related tags.  If nobody else uses the product, a dedicated tag will "hide" your question rather than attract answerers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Your workflow could look like this:

1. Analyze the pages, and create a list of the page names for each document; this list also contains the document name and the page number in the document.
2. Merge the two lists, and weed out "duplicates"
3. Create a new document by extracting the first page, and then extracting and appending the subsequent pages according to the merged list.

This can be done using (Acrobat) JavaScript, using Acrobat (Pro). Higher privileges may be needed for some actions, which means that the according function has to be installed at application-level.